# How does SOQL consider INCLUDES for multipicklist? AND or OR

Tags: soql, multi-select

i have multipicklist for industry.

I have a records which has Bank,agriculture as the selected values.

If i need to get all the records have bank and agriculture selected together. Would includes get all records which has industry of bank OR agriculture

OR

Would it give all records with Bank and agriculture ? If it doesnt what should i use to get the and condition?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the first thing to note is that according to the [help docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

> Bind expressions can't be used with other clauses, such as INCLUDES.

This means you will probably have to use a dynamic query.

The [help docs here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm) give a great run down of the ways to query multi select picklists

For your question:

1. To query the multi select picklist where Bank AND Agriculture are selected use the clause `WHERE Multi_Select__c INCLUDES ('Bank;Agriculture')`
2. To query Bank OR Agriculture as selected use the clause `WHERE Multi_Select__c INCLUDES ('Bank', 'Agriculture')`

Comment: Thanks for the link to the doc. It was slightly confusing for me reading through the doc, but your explanation was spot on

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
//your query
String query = '';

            if(multiselectList.size() > 0){
                String s = '';
                Integer i = 0;

                for(Id agId : multiselectList){
                    if(i==multiselectList.size()-1){
                        s += '\''+agId+'\'';    
                    }else{
                        s += '\''+agId+'\',';
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                query += ' AND Multi_Select__c includes('+ s +')';

            }
```

This will produce AND Multi_Select__c includes('somthing','something1') and the you can append it to your query. If you want  somthing AND something1 you can add it 'something1;something1' as in [this doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm)

Unfortunately multi select list directly can't be used in includes function it is mentioned in [this doc](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you write your query, since you want both to be present you can just use `INCLUDES` twice:

```
WHERE MultiPicklist__c INCLUDES ('Bank') AND MultiPicklist__c INCLUDES ('Agriculture')
```

I've not double checked the syntax for `INCLUDES` but I'm pretty sure this is correct.

Answer (score -1):

To query multiselect picklist which includes either of the value (OR) you can use the below code:

```
Set<String> setOfValues = new Set<String>{'A','B'};

String strMultiSelectValues = '(';

for(String eachValue : setOfValues) {`
    `strMultiSelectValues += '\'' +  eachValue + '\',';
}

strMultiSelectValues = strMultiSelectValues .removeEnd(',');`
strMultiSelectValues += ')';

String query += 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Multi_Select__c INCLUDES '+ strMultiSelectValues;
```

Your query will look like `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Multi_Select__c INCLUDES ('A','B')`

Comment: This is essentially the same as the answers posted seven years ago, but contains a number of errors. Using `String.format()` and `String.join()` would be much cleaner.